# Installed Ubuntu 16.10 alongside macOS and macOS won't boot up

Tags: dual-boot, macosx

I installed Ubuntu alongside macOS Sierra and when I restarted Ubuntu (not grub) boots automatically. When I hold down the option key Macintosh HD shows up, and when I click on it, the apple logo shows up but nothing happens (the progress bar doesn't fill up). I do not have rEFInd installed.

Comment: Do `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu. Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Note that on Mac hardware, Refind is definitely recommended. You can install it as a package in Ubuntu, and then use refind-install to automatically configure it, and this should make your boot situation a lot easier.

Comment: I got to internet recovery and was able to boot macOS, but now I can't start Ubuntu because I have no bootloader. But my recovery partition was wiped so I can't disable SIP and therefore I can't install refind (and I cannot boot to Ubuntu because I have no bootloader)